# Asp.net label does not update

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to update label's text in an event in codebehind.

in master page label is declared like:

```
<asp:Content ID="WorklistBody" ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyHolder" runat="server">


    <asp:Label id ="lblOutput" runat="server" class="textStyle4" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
    <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" ValidationGroup="SM" runat="server" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" class="textStyle4" OnServerValidate="CustomValidatorServerValidate">
        </asp:CustomValidator>

// tables and other items goes on here......
```

Developer before me used something like following to update the label;

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function ValidateComments() {
            var selOption = $('#<%= ddlActions.ClientID %> option:selected').val();
            if (selOption == 'C' || selOption == 'R' || selOption == 'U' || selOption == 'Q'|| selOption == 'P' || selOption == 'A') {
                var comment = $('#<%= txtComments.ClientID %>').val();
                comment = jQuery.trim(comment);
                if (comment == '') {
                    if (selOption == 'C') {
                        $('#<%= lblOutput.ClientID %>').text('Please enter comments before processing the transaction');
                    }
                    else if (selOption == 'R') {
                        $('#<%= lblOutput.ClientID %>').text('Please enter comments before cancelling the transaction');
                    }
                    else if (selOption == 'U' || selOption == 'Q' || selOption == 'P' || selOption == 'A') {
                        $('#<%= lblOutput.ClientID %>').text('Please enter comments before assigning the transaction');
                    }
                    window.scroll(0, 0); 
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    </script>
```

but now project expended and I gotta check a lot of logic. I want to simply update the label from codebehind.

```
public void BtnDoneclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    //logic logic logic
    lblOutput.Text = @"Please enter comments before you Process this recommendation.";


}
```

Why this doesnt update the  label? How can I update label?

I am brand new to .net environment

UPDATE:Btn Markup

```
<td align="right">
                                                             <div class="paddingStyle6 paddingStyle2">                                                                                
                                                            <asp:Button ID="btndone" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="SM"
                                                                        Text="Done" UseSubmitBehavior="True" Width="100px" OnClientClick="return ValidateComments()" OnClick="BtnDoneclick" />     

                                                            </div> 
                                                        </td>
```

Comment: BtnDoneclick doesn't follow event handler naming conventions so it won't automatically wire up. Did you wire up the onlcick event in OnInit?

Comment: No I didnt wire up the onclick event in OnInit. Do I have to do that? when I put breakpoint it seems all logic is working and when breakpoint comes to `lblOutput.Text`  it just doesnt update it.

Comment: Could you post the markup for BtnDone Button? Thanks.

Comment: Also let us know if there are any update panels.

Comment: @PatHensel I have added button mark up to bottom of my question.

Comment: @Gridly yes there is a dropdown uses updatepanel but this label I am updating is not in updatepanel. label is on top left, updatepanel is on bottom right only for dropdown.

Comment: @MordFustang, in the interest of eliminating any update panel interference -  is the button in the update panel?

Comment: @Gridly yes button is in updatepanel just below dropdown

Comment: What gridly said, or consider eliminating the update panel until the app works with visible postbacks and then add the update panel back in. Update panels triple the complexity of the code you're writing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the button is in the updatepanel then only the contents of that update panel get updated.  The label being modified is part of the page that gets ignored.

Try moving the button out of the update panel.